# Should I use a current injection method or voltage injection method?

Tags: power-electronics

I am currently designing an earth fault detection system for 110V DC transmission line. As you can see in the diagram, I have a long line of monitoring equipment powering these monitors (which I will model using resistors, capacitors and inductors). I am currently designing an earth fault tracer (ie. earthing occurs in one of the parallel branches) for this DC transmission line by injecting a square wave pulse into the system. In order to do this should I be using a constant current source or a constant voltage source?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEceE0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: what does the fault condition you are trying to detect look like?

Comment: Imagine the space between R1 and R3 gets grounded

Comment: it seems to me that a voltmeter would locate that fault more easily than any other instrument.

Comment: I was hoping to use a current tracer to trace the fault current created by a voltage/current source. Simply using a voltmeter is too hard because I actually have a lot of monitoring equipment.

Comment: Is ground the bottom line on that diagram? I was assuming it was.

Comment: @Jasen no this is a "floating" DC transmission system, so it is ungrounded

Comment: ah! that makes a difference.  probably you should model both types of injection and see how it effects your setup

Comment: @Jasen is there any sort of free software that you would recommend using for such modelling?

Comment: some sort of spice, or just use Ohm's Law.  if you use a perfect current source you get infinite voltage if there is no earth fault (until the insulation fails). if you use a voltage source a fault could will burn up the wires,  so you need something in-between.